# Ubuntu 18.04 don't recognize Droidcam as a sound input device

Tags: 18.04, sound, webcam, input-devices, droidcam

I am trying to use my android device as a webcam. I am using Droidcam and video is being shared properly. But I still have no voice.
Ubuntu doesn't recognize Driodcam as a sound input device.
I don't know what is causing the problem and how should I debug the process.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Works perfectly also in linux client. Checked on Ubuntu 20.04

*Seems not impemented in linux client yet:
https://github.com/aramg/droidcam/issues/1*

Comment: Sound support has been implemented in Droidcam. This answer should be updated.